# Need help formatting an xpath within python

Tags: python, xpath, formatting

I need to format ("//button([@id='step-%s' % stepnum]") so that the %s will change. I'm very new with python so I'm sorry if there is an blindingly obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
stepnum = 123
formatted = format("//button([@id='step-%s']" % str(stepnum))
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If I have misinterpreted the question, please add a comment to go with the downvote.

Comment: Why the call to `format()`, since `%` is already doing the job?

Comment: Only because OP didn't specify whether his formatted string was to be printed directly or used for something else. Updated to be more clear.

Comment: The string in question is an XPath expression - so, it is almost certainly not printed out, but evaluated against XML data.